# Unable to connect to Solace

Tags: java, solace

I am trying to connect Solace using my Java code

```
properties.setProperty(JCSMPProperties.HOST, "XXXXXXXXXX:80");
properties.setProperty(JCSMPProperties.USERNAME, "USERNAME");
properties.setProperty(JCSMPProperties.PASSWORD,  "PASSWORD");
properties.setProperty(JCSMPProperties.VPN_NAME, "VPN_NAME");
//properties.setProperty(JCSMPProperties.)
final JCSMPSession session = JCSMPFactory.onlyInstance().createSession(properties);
session.connect();
```

while connecting I am getting the following error and I have no clue as of why.

```
Error communicating with the router. cause: java.io.IOException: Could not read valid SMF Header from network. found smf version=0 
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Could not read valid SMF Header from network. found smf version=0
```

Can someone please explain me why we get this error.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I see you are connecting to port 80. Is that correct? It should be 55555.

For example,

```
final JCSMPProperties properties = new JCSMPProperties();
properties.setProperty(JCSMPProperties.HOST, "hostname:55555");
properties.setProperty(JCSMPProperties.USERNAME, "USERNAME");
properties.setProperty(JCSMPProperties.PASSWORD, "PASSWORD");
properties.setProperty(JCSMPProperties.VPN_NAME, "VPN_NAME");
final JCSMPSession session = JCSMPFactory.onlyInstance().createSession(properties);

session.connect();
```

Comment: tried connecting to 55555 too, I was still getting the same error

Comment: Login to the Solace CLI and see if the right ports are exposed. You can do that by running "show service" command.

I would also recommend sharing this on https://solace.community/